# How do i resolve this Error: Cannot find module 'lodash.set'.after running nodemon serve

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I ran npm install on a project i cloned from github...After trying to start the server with `node server`.I get this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash.set'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\AFROPEPE\CLIE\msafiriv4\BakiTravel\node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:5:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\AFROPEPE\CLIE\msafiriv4\BakiTravel\server\api.js:7:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
```

Here is my package.json file

```
Package.Json 
{
  "name": "mean-rsvp-auth0",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "dev": "concurrently \"ng serve\" \"NODE_ENV=dev node\"",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.3",
    "auth0-js": "^9.7.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-unless": "^0.5.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^1.3.0",
    "loaderjs": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
    "method-override": "^2.3.8",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.11",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.6.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "ajv": "^6.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "4.3.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "5.10.0",
    "typescript": "2.9.2"
  }
}
{
  "name": "mean-rsvp-auth0",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "dev": "concurrently \"ng serve\" \"NODE_ENV=dev node\"",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.3",
    "auth0-js": "^9.7.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-unless": "^0.5.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^1.3.0",
    "loaderjs": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
    "method-override": "^2.3.8",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.11",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.6.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "ajv": "^6.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "4.3.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "5.10.0",
    "typescript": "2.9.2"
  }
}
```

I tried installing the **lodash.set**  dependency from npm but it still doesn't solve my problem.I also dont actively need the dependency i was thinking a way around it would be to remove it entirely how could i do that.Could it also be that my angular version is to blame.

Comment: Maybe a versioning issue.  Perhaps one of the dependent libraries leveraged lodash with a wildcard in the version and the lodash.set is no longer supported in the current version?  Isn't set one of the new types in the ES*?  It wouldn't surprise me to see it deprecatd in libraries otherwise supporting that type.  Perhaps share the package.json?

Comment: @akaphenom I have updated my question to include package.json

Comment: okay that doesn't look to out of sorts.  How about an `ls` of your node_modules directory?